# Calculation cpu and memory exUnits on transaction submit is different then on transaction build?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, cardano-cli

I am trying to build a non-optimized script and during the `cardano-cli build transaction` I got an error:

```
Command failed: transaction build  Error: The following scripts have execution failures:
the script for transaction input 2 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with: 
The Plutus script evaluation failed: An error has occurred:  User error:
The budget was overspent. Final negative state: ({ cpu: 3356097790
| mem: -240
})
Script debugging logs: 
the script for transaction input 3 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with: 
The Plutus script evaluation failed: An error has occurred:  User error:
The budget was overspent. Final negative state: ({ cpu: 3356097790
| mem: -240
})
Script debugging logs: 
the script for transaction input 4 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with: 
The Plutus script evaluation failed: An error has occurred:  User error:
The budget was overspent. Final negative state: ({ cpu: 3356097790
| mem: -240
})
```

After optimization (BuiltinData -> BuiltinData -> BuiltinData -> () and custom ScriptContext)  `build` succeeded but then `submit` started to report error:

```
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (ExUnitsTooBigUTxO (WrapExUnits {unWrapExUnits = ExUnits' {exUnitsMem' = 16000000, exUnitsSteps' = 10000000000}}) (WrapExUnits {unWrapExUnits = ExUnits' {exUnitsMem' = 18581638, exUnitsSteps' = 6410063947}}))))])
```

Why does this happen? Shouldn't calculations be the same for `build` and `submit` so if it passes `build` it should pass also `submit`?